# How to go back to the previous step in a Swirl() course?

Tags: r, swirl

I am doing a linear regression course where I am currently creating dummy variables. I had stopped it midway a few days ago and resumed it now. I would like to back up a step so that I can remember what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but for future reference: that is not in the options. You can see all possible actions you can do with info(), which returns:

```
| When you are at the R prompt (>):
| -- Typing skip() allows you to skip the current question.
| -- Typing play() lets you experiment with R on your own; swirl will ignore
| what you do...
| -- UNTIL you type nxt() which will regain swirl's attention.
| -- Typing bye() causes swirl to exit. Your progress will be saved.
| -- Typing main() returns you to swirl's main menu.
| -- Typing info() displays these options again.
```

Therefore your best bet is to type: `main()` and then use `skip()` multiple times to get the result you desire.